# POS application using JAVAPOS and Tysso POS

Tags: java, windows-xp, point-of-sale, javapos

I want to develop a POS application in JAVA for this POS http://www.fametech.com.tw/product_content.php?id=67

Operating system is Windowx XP with the POS connected via comm port 3 . I have only seen the comm port 3 in the device manager.

My problem is to be able to (in order of priority)

1. print receipt,
2. opening the cash till
3. displaying the total to the customer

I have learned about http://www.javapos.com/ library and I have found that there is a need to provide a jpos.xml file for it to work with the javapos library together with a jar provided by the manufacturer.

I have search on the manufacturer website but i did not find any java jar or jpos.xml.

How can i make it work with javapos?

Also, there is already a software with the pos but written in foxpro or vb.net (i am not quite sure as i do not these languages well). But this program is already working with opening the till, printing the receipt and displaying content to the customer via the customer display. Can i use the existing software with java to make it work?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jzebra library which is open sourced!

Comment: thank you. For the printer, it is ok, but what about opening the cash till?

Comment: Depends what kind of till you use but most tills are plugged in via the printer so you can sent a command to the printer and it opens the till.

Comment: In javascript I use 
`applet.append(chr(27) + "\x70" + "\x30" + chr(25) + chr(25) + "\r");//open drawer`
`applet.append(chr(27) + chr(112) + chr(48) + chr(123) + chr(123) + "\r");//open drawer` for ESCP printers

Comment: thanks. I will try it and let you know. but one thing, you are using vbscript?

Comment: I got this from the manufacturer. Do you know what it means?
`The Cash Drawer kick-out function is controlled by relaying the Control pin address 280H bit 4 as following:

Output  a pulse  0 => 1( 500m second)  => 0  to control pin => cash drawer active open => close the cash drawer.`